# How to show result sum of many table in sql server

Tags: database, sql-server-2012

I have a problem with sql in my project.

This is my Database:
[image]

How do I show the result of `sum(cthdban.soluongmh) as totalban` and `sum(cthdnhap.soluongnhap) as totalnhap` in one row?

Example: idloaihang | idmathang | giabanmh | totalban | gianhap | totalnhap

I have tried the following:

```
select  mathang.idloaihang
       ,mathang.idmathang
       ,mathang.tenmathang
       ,cthdban.giabanmh
       ,sum(cthdban.soluongmh) as totalban
       ,cthdnhap.gianhap
       ,sum(cthdnhap.soluongnhap) as totalnhap

from hdban
    ,cthdban
    ,mathang
    ,hdnhap
    ,cthdnhap

where cthdnhap.idmathang = mathang.idmathang
    and hdban.idhdban = cthdban.idhdban
    and hdnhap.idhdnhap = cthdnhap.idhdnhap
    and cthdban.idmathang = mathang.idmathang
    and mathang.idloaihang = 'BI02'
    and hdban.ngayhd between'11/30/2016 00:00:00' and '12/1/2016 23:59:59'
    or  hdnhap.ngaynhap between'12/1/2016 00:00:00' and '12/1/2016 23:59:59'

group by mathang.idloaihang
        ,mathang.idmathang
        ,mathang.tenmathang
        ,cthdban.giabanmh
        ,cthdnhap.gianhap
```

but my result is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try it using JOIN clauses

```
select  
    mathang.idloaihang
    ,mathang.idmathang
    ,mathang.tenmathang
    ,cthdban.giabanmh
    ,sum(cthdban.soluongmh) as totalban
    ,cthdnhap.gianhap
    ,sum(cthdnhap.soluongnhap) as totalnhap
from 
    hdban
    left join cthdban
        on hdban.idhdban = cthdban.idhdban
    left mathang
        on cthdnhap.idmathang = mathang.idmathang
    left join hdnhap
        on hdnhap.idhdnhap = cthdnhap.idhdnhap
    left join cthdnhap
        cthdban.idmathang = mathang.idmathang
where 
    mathang.idloaihang = 'BI02'
    and hdban.ngayhd between'11/30/2016 00:00:00' and '12/1/2016 23:59:59'
    or  hdnhap.ngaynhap between'12/1/2016 00:00:00' and '12/1/2016 23:59:59'
group by 
    mathang.idloaihang
    ,mathang.idmathang
    ,mathang.tenmathang
    ,cthdban.giabanmh
    ,cthdnhap.gianhap
```

Comment: add your actual sentence to the question

Comment: no, there is something wrong in your WHERE clause, let me check your tables

Comment: what is the relaton between `hdban` and `hdnhap`?

Comment: idea of you is Relationship?
hdban and hdnhap do not relationship
you can see image in post about relation

Comment: i think problem is line code `hdban.ngayhd between'11/30/2016 00:00:00' and '12/1/2016 23:59:59'
    or  hdnhap.ngaynhap between'12/1/2016 00:00:00' and '12/1/2016 23:59:59' ` but i don't know how do choose  2 condition ?

Comment: use not between () AND not between() instead.

Comment: if i sell item and receipt item from provider: Result show in 1 rows 
`idGroupItem | iditem | pricesell | sumnumsell | priceReceipt | sumnumreceipt`
if i sell item and not receipt item from provider: Result show in 1 row
`idGroupItem | iditem | pricesell | sumnumsell |0| 0 `
and reverse
This is idea of me